# Qual o motivo de algumas funções que trabalham com strings em C iniciarem com *?

Tags: c, string, ponteiro, array

Em uma de nossas aulas fomos ensinados que quando uma função recebe como parâmetro um vetor ela na verdade está recebendo a posição de memória na qual ele está alocado não sendo necessário portanto retornarmos nenhum valor pois o que será executado dentro do procedimento automaticamente estará alterando no vetor/*string* em si. Porém algumas funções estão iniciando com um `*` e retornando um vetor. Ex:

```
int strlen(char *s){
  int i = 0;
  while(s[i]!='\0'){
    i++;
  }
  return i;
}
```

Exemplo de uma função padrão que retorna o numero de elementos na *string*.

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, char *orig){
    int i;
    for(i=0; orig[i]!='\0'; i++){
        dest[i] = orig[i];
    }  
    dest[i] = '\0';
    return dest;
}
```

Exemplo de uma função que está retornando uma *string*/vetor.

Qual é o motivo de algumas funções iniciarem com `*` e consequentemente retornarem um vetor?

Comment: O asterisco faz parte do retorno. `strcpy` é uma função que retorna `char*`: ponteiro para char (o fato do asterisco ficar perto do nome da função ou do nome do tipo não faz diferença).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Porque essa função em específico deve fazer isso. Olha no nome dela: *string copy*. Ela deve copiar uma *string*. O que você aprendeu está correto, se você recebe um ponteiro, tudo o que mexer no conteúdo apontado por essa variável mudará o conteúdo da memória original, já que é o mesmo local. Mas neste caso você não quer mexer no que já existe, você quer criar uma cópia desse conteúdo para outro lugar. Então precisa criar um novo objeto, não o mesmo objeto. Aí depois dessa função terminar de criar esse novo objeto ela deve retornar onde está esse objeto, por isso ela retorna um ponteiro para esse **novo objeto**.

Outra forma de garantir isso é passar esse endereço como argumento. E de fato isto ocorre nesta função. Talvez sua dúvida seja porque fazer as duas coisas.

A filosofia do C é sempre deixar o programador cuidar do gerenciamento de memória, porque ele provavelmente fará o melhor para cada situação. Então se você é que tem que alocar a memória para a cópia da *string* você deve passar esse endereço como argumento, e de fato isto está sendo feito.

Aí de acordo com o que aprendeu a cópia será colocada neste endereço passado, mudando esse objeto novo. Ótimo, está resolvido, não precisa retornar algo, certo?

Sim, certo. Mas é comum o uso desta função para alocar em outra variável e por conveniência se deu a opção de retornar o mesmo endereço que você passou para a função usar como novo objeto.

Melhor fazer

```
char* nova = strcpy(malloc(10), "texto");
```

do que

```
char* nova = malloc(10);
strcpy(nova, "texto");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/MutableString.c).

Comment: Compreendo. Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Comment: Nunca imaginei usar o retorno do `malloc` como parâmetro direto de `strcpy` e coisas do gênero

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado uma coisa qeu eu falao muito e muita gente não porque ninguém quer ver suas falhas apontadas, é que se você não souber o que cada caractere do código faz, até os espaços, ainda não dominou a programação. Quando começa pensar no que pode ir ali, quase como um compilador, começa produzir código melhores. O resto é seguir as receitas que aprendeu. Eu mesmo ainda deslizo aqui e ali. Muita gente muito experiente têm certas dificuldades porque seguem receitas em vez procurar a melhor solução. Elas acham que não é necessário, o que os faz senior em certo ponto e junior em outro.

Comment: É algo que uma vez eu li, tratado neste artigo [**Conheça seu compilador**](https://www.propelics.com/talking-code-get-to-know-your-compiler/) e  nesta apresentação [**Otimização de código fonte**](https://www.fefe.de/know-your-compiler.pdf).

Comment: Exatamente, tem que conhecer cada detalhe. Se procurar eu falo dessas otimizações aqui no site.

Answer (score 2):

> Sendo pedântico quanto à leitura de declaração de função

Esse engano acontece devido à Escola de Estilo de código de quem escreveu essa função. Vou escrever cabeçalhos equivalentes, cada um em um estilo distinto:

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, char *orig);
char* strcpy(char *dest, char *orig);
char *strcpy(char* dest, char* orig);
char * strcpy(char * dest, char * orig);
char* strcpy(char* dest, char* orig);
```

Qual a diferença entre as declarações acima? Para o compilador, nenhuma. Há para quem escreve e para quem lê, mas isso fica apenas a nível de estilo de código.

> Por que existem essas diferentes escolas de estilo?

Bem, cada uma tem uma proposta, um valor defendido. É meio como questionar "se tem o cubismo, por que usaram o dadaísmo?"...

Se quem escrevesse com o indicador de ponteiros sempre ao lado esquerdo achasse que o indicador de ponteiro deveria estar isolado das palavras que o cercam, o estilo da esquerda teria sucumbido faz tempo.

Eu sou da escola que, em declaração de variáveis, uso o indicador de ponteiro sempre colado no nome da variável. Por quê? Beleza conta? Além disso, porque as duas declarações a seguir são idênticas:

```
int *p, i;
int* p, i;
```

Em ambos os casos, está se criando um ponteiro `p` e um inteiro `i`. A ideia da escola que sigo é mostrar sempre na variável que ela tem esse indicador de ponteiro, evitando que alguém, sem querer, interprete que o `i` seja um outro ponteiro para inteiro.

Assim, cria-se o hábito de sempre separar o tipo do `*`, o que pode não ser salutar. Em funções, por exemplo, não enxergo motivo de desambiguação de leitura, apenas uso porque sim. Note que, como cada argumento vem precedido de seu tipo, também se torna irrelevante o motivo de melhoria da leitura.

## Resumo

Você não diria que `char* strcpy(char* dest, char* orig);` começa com `*`, diria? Então ela não retorna um vetor porque começa com `*`, mas retorna um ponteiro porque o **tipo de retorno declarado** é ponteiro de caracter `char*`.